# HILO game, when number is not found

Tags: c++, recursion

i'm working on a HILO game for school, where the program guesses the users number by asking if the number is higher or lower. I have the code working where it guesses right, but i also need a case for when the user "cheats", number is guessed but user chooses high or low again.
this is what i have for my code:

```
    void GuessNumber(int lowVal, int highVal)
     {
        int midVal = 0;
        char userAnswer = '-';

        midVal = (highVal + lowVal) / 2;

        cout << "Is it " << midVal << " (l,y,h)? " << endl;
        cin >> userAnswer;

        if ((userAnswer != 'l') && (userAnswer != 'h'))
      {
         cout << "Your number is " << midVal << endl;
      }
       else {
         if (userAnswer == 'h')
          {
            GuessNumber(lowVal, midVal);
          }
            else if (userAnswer == 'l')
            {
             GuessNumber(midVal, highVal);
            }
           }

             return;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not ask the user higher/lower unless you do not know.  So the only time you can detect cheating is when you know the answer is one of two values (N or N+1) and you ask the user if it's N and they say it's lower (or you ask if it's N+1 and they say higher).

All other cases are not worth worrying about, because either you already know the exact answer (user cannot cheat you, just tell them you know the answer), or there are at least three possible answers left (in which case any response could be correct).

Comment: if the user chooses 30 and at the end of the program he gets asked if his number is 30 and the user chooses low or high, the program needs to print "you cheated" when it runs out of options. i don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: Why bother asking the user when you know?  If you insist on that, then just respond by saying "you cheated" if you know the answer is 30 and you ask if it's 30 and they don't say yes.  In other words, if the solution space ever becomes empty, they cheated.

Comment: John Zwinck, thanks for your response, i think that might be what i'm trying to do. To print "you cheated" when the it becomes empty. How could i check for that. ( as far as why i need to do it, the assignment just requires it)

Comment: Just check if the solution space is empty.  That means there is no possible answer left.  I am not going to write the code for you.

Comment: i wasn't asking you to write the code for me. Thanks for your time.